# Is there a way to escape to GRUB2 before system gets to the GUI log in screen?

Tags: grub2, login-screen, boot-failure

After upgrading to 11.04 on a Dell Dimension E310 I cannot login. My keyboard and mouse have locked up. I would like to escape to GRUB2 to allow me to investigate the problem I have. I cannot even boot from a LiveCD or USB stick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Holding down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key during boot should stop the boot process at the GRUB prompt.